# custom search view

Tags: android, xml, layout, searchview

I am trying to create custom search view to appear when I click search icon in the action bar menu item. It works but when i open it there is extra space on top of the search bar. Can some one please tell me what I am doing wrong. I am also posting the code below. Thank you in advance.  [image]

Main Activity xml

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.abhi.searchview.MainActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<include layout="@layout/content_main" />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />
```

Search_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<merge 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<View
    android:id="@id/search_shadow"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/shadow_overlay"
    android:visibility="gone" />

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@id/search_cardview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="2dp"
    android:maxHeight="0.9dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/search_height"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:gravity="start|center_vertical"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@id/search_nav"
                android:layout_width="56dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:contentDescription="@string/search"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:scaleType="centerInside" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText
                android:id="@id/search_edit_text"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="start|center_vertical"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:ems="10"
                android:gravity="start|center_vertical"
                android:imeOptions="actionSearch|flagNoExtractUi"
                android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:paddingEnd="16dp"
                android:paddingStart="8dp"
                android:privateImeOptions="nm"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden" />



            <ImageView
                android:id="@id/search_extra"
                android:layout_width="48dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:contentDescription="@string/search"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:scaleType="center"
                android:visibility="gone" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@id/search_clear"
                android:layout_width="48dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:contentDescription="@string/search"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:scaleType="center" />

        </LinearLayout>


        <View
            android:id="@id/search_divider"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="?android:attr/listDivider" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@id/search_recycler"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:overScrollMode="never"
            android:visibility="gone" />

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

MainActivity.kt

```
override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu): Boolean {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu)
    if (searchView == null) 
    searchView = bindSearchView(menu, R.id.action_search)


    return true
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i figured it out. i was setting the top margin in my code for the search_view card element. That fixed the problem. There is nothing wrong with the xml files. Thank you anyways